# how to select input ID using span, I'm facing bug in selecting ID dropdown

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I am new to Selenium, and in learning phase, would be appreciable for help:

my Code:

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, UnexpectedTagNameException
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

date_after_month = datetime.today() + relativedelta(months=1)
print('Today: ', datetime.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
print('After Month:', date_after_month.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))

now = datetime.now()  # current date and time
year = now.strftime("%Y")
month = now.strftime("%m")
month_coming = date_after_month.strftime("%m")
x_current_month = year + str("P") + month
x = year + str("P") + month_coming
print(x_current_month)
print(x)
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://epsportal.int.net.nokia.com/')
time.sleep(3)
# With Silent_Login
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="silentLoginSmall"]').click()
# silentpopup
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="popUpButton"]').click()
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="navNodeAnchor_1_3"]').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="navNodeAnchor_2_1"]').click()
time.sleep(5)
# 1Selecting a Dropdown option in Selenium WebDriver using the value attribute;assigning variable'drp'and using
# 'selectness dropdown1 = Select(driver.find_element('id','//*[@id="WD17"]'))
drp = driver.find_element_by_class_name("urCoB2Whl")
```

Facing error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anmourya\Documents\Python test\testingggg_select.py", line 40, in <module>
    drp = driver.find_element_by_class_name("urCoB2Whl")
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class_name'
```

HTML Code:

```
<span id="WD19-r" class="urCoB2Whl">
  <input id="WD19" autocomplete="off" value="2022P10 : 23/09/2022 TO 27/10/2022 - OPE" readonly="" ct="CB" lsdata="{7:'WD1A',8:'1',10:'2022P10 : 23/09/2022 TO 27/10/2022 - OPE'}" lsevents="{Select:[{ResponseData:'delta',ClientAction:'submit'},{}]}" tabindex="0" ti="0" class="urEdf2TxtRadius urEdf2TxtEnbl lsEdf3TxtHlpBtn lsEdfLeftBrdRadius" style="width:42ex;">
  <input type="text" readonly="" id="WD19-btn" tabindex="-1" ti="-1" class="urBorderBox lsEdf2HlpRadius lsEdf3HlpBtn lsEdf3HlpBtnCoB">
</span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am not a python guru, but the answer to your problem lies in your error message: `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class_name'`

A quick search revealed that you need to use the standard `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'myclass')` to find by class.

You also need to treat your dropdown as a regular web element because it's not a `<select>` element even though it looks like one in the UI. To handle dynamic elements like these, I find it best to click on the element to trigger the dynamic item display, then search for the text of the specific item I wish to select.

I found this information here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html